# Prometheus Node exporter systemd collector not collecting service alias names

Tags: prometheus, systemd, prometheus-node-exporter

Systemd allows us to specify alias names for a service and it creates a symlink to that service when enabled. By default the systemd collector doesnt seem to be collecting the metrics for the alias service. Any config to make it collect metrics for the alias service as well?

Example:

foo.service is a symlink for bar.service

systemd collector only has metrics for bar.service

We need to collect metrics for both the services even though both are going to be same all the time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob, well it's is not about systemd really, it's more about node_exporter. Also why close, and not just flag to move?

Comment: @markalex His specific question is about configuration. This also doesn't contain any code if it's a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it could (nor should) be done, but if you want really qualified opinion on if it is possible, you could create `question` in [Node exporter issues](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues).

Better way would be to create [metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) for your target, and add alias info to metrics.
This way you will be aware that `foo.service` is an alias.

Config would look something like this:

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__name__, unit_name]
  regex: "node_systemd_unit_.+;bar\.service"
  target_label: unit_alias
  replacement: "foo.service"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will raise it in Node exporter questions as well.